# Why UIImageview did not showing url image in Xcode 7?

Tags: ios, url, uiimageview, xcode7

I am working on iOS application using new version `Xcode 7` and `iOS 9`. I am facing the following issue.

`UIImageView` is not showing images coming through URL. I am using the following code but `imageview` did not show images.

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://XXX.XX.XX.XXX:XXXX/XXXXXXXX/7339bec316b7404299c582f5904a6d3f.jpeg"];
 NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url];
 UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data ];
 imageview.image=img;
```

I don't know what is the issue in `Xcode 7`, but it is working previous version.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Check your log. It certainly contains a message regarding Apple Transport Security.

Comment: Thanks. Now its working. I changed info.plist file.

Comment: how did you make it work?

Comment: Edit the info.plist file   <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>  
     <dict>  
          <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>  
     </dict>

Answer (score 0):

The above code should work for synchronous loading of image into ImageView. Make sure URL and imageView code is right. Alternatively you can use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) for loading of images into imageView. It has Asynchronous loading, caching and many more options like post response processing which are very useful. It's very simple to implement too. Sample code is below.

```
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>

[_profilePic sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl]
                  placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholderIcon"]];
```

This will populate your imageView with a placeholder and when the image is fetched it replaces placeholder with it. Check out the github project for more options.